# Android Studio Update

Tags: android-studio, updates, conflict

Conflicts when updating:

> File: NOTICE.txt Action: Validate Problem: Absent
>
> File: Install-Linux-tar.txt Action: Validate Problem: Absent

[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksqxa.png)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just ran across this issue, and found a solution.

The self-update seems to be very picky about these files. Simply creating empty ones or even copying the ones from a wrong version doesn't work.

You need to download the exact package for your current (old) version, extract these two files and place them in the correct location.

In my case, using Manjaro Linux and upgrading from Android Studio 3.5.3 to the latest version (3.6.1), I downloaded:
`https://dl.google.com/dl/android/studio/ide-zips/3.5.3.0/android-studio-ide-191.80264235-linux.tar.gz`

Notice that you need the exact version (in my case `3.5.3.0`) and build number (in my case `191.80264235`). I found these in the [PKGBUILD](https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/commit/PKGBUILD?h=android-studio&id=43d6c21ca1eea2dfb43f98968dce6f6532e1a1aa) for my current Android Studio version.

Extracted the two files, and copied them to `/opt/android-studio`

Finally I ran Android Studio again (as root, to have the necessary write permissions for that directory), clicked to upgrade and it worked.

Comment: I used https://developer.android.com/studio/archive.html, your link is broken for me(

Comment: Awesome. Works! Just verified that changing the permissions and file stats is not necessary FYI.

Comment: @Nick thanks, I'll remove the permissions part from the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Running as root did not work for me so I performed

```
 sudo chown -R \<username> /opt/android-studio
```

Then I copied in the two files per above after extracting them.

```
 cp -p /extract_directory/android-studio/NOTICE.txt /opt/android-studio

 cp -p /extract_directory/android-studio/Install-Linux-tar.txt /opt/android-studio
```